# Setting Location of JPanel in JFrame Not Working

Tags: java

I've been messing around with this for a while, but no matter what, I can't set the location of the JPanel in the JFrame. I'm a bit of a noob, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. Here's the code, when I run it, the JPanel doesn't seem to be at the coordinates I intend for it to be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.setLayout(null);
    p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p.setBounds(100,100,100,100);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setSize(400,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Don't use null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. Learn and use layout managers instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: You shouldn't use null layout, as suggested. Get familiar with layouts, as they'll provide more sturdy component placement (not all monitors render share the same resolution or aspect ratio). For your case, you never adjusted the layout of the `JFrame`, so it's still using it's default `BorderLayout`. You adjusted the layout of the panel not the frame.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, I'll look into it!